# "requires" (pyproject.toml) with a local package in editable mode

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I am using a `pyproject.toml` file to allow me to use third party packages during my build.  (For example, I'd like to use the `toml` package in `setup.up`.)  When I add a local package to "requires" (installed in editable mode), the build doesn't see the package.  Is there a way to include local packages in my `pyproject.toml` other than explicitly deploying them to pypi?

Here's what my `pyproject.toml` file looks like currently:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "toml", "my_local_package"]
```

Comment: PEP 518 states that `requires` is _a value of a list of strings representing PEP 508 dependencies_. Although PEP 508 grammar allows local files, [looks like `pip` doesn't implement it](https://discuss.python.org/t/what-is-the-correct-interpretation-of-path-based-pep-508-uri-reference/2815), so I'd say not possible yet.

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/pypa/pep517/issues/43

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = [
  "setuptools >= 61.2",
  "versioningit @ file:///Users/basnijholt/Downloads/versioningit",
  "wheel",
]
```

Comment: What if I need a relative path? I have been studying PEP 508, but can't get it right.

I'm thinking of something like "my-package @ file:relative/path"

Comment: Apparently it was explicitly disallowed, but I do not really understand why.
https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/discussions/2951